# Python Gitlab API invite group to project

Tags: python, api, gitlab, documentation, python-gitlab

I'm trying to add a gitlab group to a project after the project is created. I can see in the Gitlab API documentation that it's possible to invite a MEMBER to a group to or a  project (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/invitations.html)

It's however possible to invite a group to a project from the Gitlab Dashboard when navigating the Members menu, under Project information.

[image]

How would I go about adding a group to a project after it is created using the python-gitlab API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution at https://python-gitlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/gl_objects/projects.html#project-members

It is important to note the Gitlab have two types for projects as stated in https://python-gitlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/gl_objects/groups.html#group-members

> GroupProject objects returned by this API call are very limited, and
> do not provide all the features of Project objects. If you need to
> manipulate projects, create a new Project object:

```
first_group_project = group.projects.list()[0]

manageable_project = gl.projects.get(first_group_project.id, lazy=True)
```

To share the project with a group you need the manageable_project object.

```
gl = gitlab.Gitlab(settings.GITLABURL, settings.GITLABTOKEN, api_version=4, ssl_verify=False)

gitlab_group = self.gl.groups.list(search="group_name")[0]
project_object = self.gl.projects.get(gitlab_group.id, lazy=True)

project_object.share(project_object.id, gitlab.MAINTAINER_ACCESS)
```

The result:
[image]